# Wordpress custom template CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I apply CSS for a custom template in wordpress? In the theme I'm using, the background's suppose to be light-green, but when I create a template on PHP the background color is gone. And for example, if I assign a page the default template, the color is back. How can I add a CSS file so my custom template can have the same color or another color in case I want it to be different? Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is kinda sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your template imports your header which usually imports the style.css file of your theme.

Also you can make use of the admin style editor found under appearance on Wordpress admin menu to write custom css rules for your template.

Comment: How I import it? At the beggining of my template I have 
<?php
/* Template Name"Name
*/
get_header();
?>
but nothing happens

Comment: Did you build your theme from scratch?

Comment: Well, not the theme. I installed a theme, then created a PHP file to create a template for a page.

Comment: Please look at this https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/

Comment: When the article mentions CSS it just show the code for the CSS, not from where it got it from, where to put it or anything, but thanks bro.

Comment: I think your custom template does not communicate with the header of your theme. Start from there. Courage